# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props = props')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to implement task function that would allow me to display different task just by reading them from TASK_DATA.js but i got an "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props = props')" and i got kind of mixed up and i dont know where to start to get out of that. Probably there is easy way out but i need someone else advice to clear my thoughts out.

```
const TASK_DATA = [
 {
    id: 't1',
    title: 'Application Setup',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel gravida orci. Proin odio ex, elementum eu malesuada sit amet, congue eget dui. Suspendisse sem ligula, pharetra non aliquam non, tincidunt rutrum nunc. Suspendisse faucibus, diam et facilisis pellentesque, ligula justo posuere tellus, vitae viverra nunc erat ut quam. Praesent semper elit suscipit blandit iaculis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in consequat nulla, sit amet semper augue. Donec cursus efficitur nibh, vel cursus velit faucibus et. Morbi sit amet augue tellus. Vivamus sapien justo, ullamcorper aliquet lectus a, interdum facilisis nulla. Suspendisse lobortis pulvinar mauris, pulvinar tempus dolor. Aliquam commodo gravida arcu, dictum gravida neque sagittis vel',
    status: 'done'
 },
 {
    id: 't2',
    title: 'Administrator Panel',
    content: 'Fusce tincidunt libero eget orci facilisis vulputate. In varius pretium scelerisque. Vestibulum leo arcu, dictum nec feugiat non, sagittis sit amet neque. Ut vulputate sem leo, eu placerat dolor ultricies at. Mauris et massa diam. Ut quis pulvinar dolor, vestibulum aliquet est. Fusce ut cursus lacus. Vestibulum accumsan gravida ornare. Maecenas mollis mattis elit, sed porttitor erat consectetur sit amet.',
    status: 'done'
 },
 {
    id: 't3',
    title: 'Connect Admin with Frontend',
    content: 'Etiam malesuada tincidunt semper. Nunc dolor nulla, luctus id tempus ut, dignissim quis diam. Aliquam placerat ex at sapien pellentesque bibendum. Nam eget metus id mauris dapibus pharetra eu quis odio. Aliquam facilisis bibendum neque, feugiat consequat libero ultricies et. Ut tristique justo lobortis finibus gravida. Etiam sed arcu in augue efficitur maximus vitae sit amet tellus.',
    status: 'current'
 },
 {
    id: 't4',
    title: 'Book review status',
    content: 'At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.',
    status: 'lock'
 }
];

export default TASK_DATA;
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component() {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }


  
  render(props) {
    props.tasks.map(task => <Task 
      key={task.id}
      id={task.id}
      title={task.title}
      content={task.content}
      status={task.status}
      />)
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Menu
          <p>nerds.family</p>
          <p>img kółeczko</p>
        </div>

        <Bar/>
        <hr className="sep"></hr>
        <Router>
          <Window/>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Content/>}/>
            <Route path="/task-1" element={<Task />}/>
            <Route path="/task-2"></Route>
            <Route path="/task-3"></Route>
            <Route path="/task-4"></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
      
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Task.js

```
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="taskText">
                <p>{props.content}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="taskCrit">
                <h1>Acceptance Criteria</h1>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
}

export default Task;
```

Window.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check';
import ArrowForwardIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForward';
import LockIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Lock';

function Window () {
        
        return (
            
            <div className="window">
                <div className="header">
                    YOUR TASKS
                </div>
                <hr></hr>
                <div className="tasksList">
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to='/task-1'><CheckIcon className={this.task1.status}/>{this.task1.title}</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to='/task-2'><CheckIcon className={this.task2.status}/>{this.task2.title}</Link></li>
                        <li className="curr"><Link to='/task-3'><ArrowForwardIcon className={this.task3.status}/>{this.task3.title}</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to='/task-4'><LockIcon className={this.task4.status}/>{this.task4.title}</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    
    
}

export default Window;
```

Comment: In App.js you are expecting tasks array to be passed down, 

I,m not sure if you are passing it down or how you expect to receive it?

Comment: Errors come with line numbers, get in the habit of trying to debug the error yourself and figure out what line it's coming from. Your code doesn't mention `this.props` so we probably can't help you and your question may be closed. I do see your code references `this.task2.status` and it looks like you made up those properties without ever setting them, so that may be causing the error, or a different one. Please edit this question (don't put debugging details in comments) to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: You also call `props.tasks.map` which doesn't do anything, because `map` returns an array, but you don't assign the result to a variable, nor output the result of the map in JSX by putting it inside of `{` `}` where you return the JSX elements.